# "appealed to by"

Tags: grammar

> It is an analogy **appealed to by** Graham but that the philosopher
>   rejects

The part "appealed to by" sounds grammatically wrong. Shouldn't it be "appealed by"?

Comment: _"Graham appealed to it"_ is the active form of the passive clause _"It is **appealed to by** Graham."_ It is grammatically sound.

Comment: Graham does not 'appeal' the analogy--ask some higher authority to abrogate it--he 'appeals **to** it' as if it were itself an 'authority' which could validate whatever point he is arguing.

Comment: @StoneyB is the OP taking this _appeal_ as transitive, do you think?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Indeed I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only transitive use of "appeal" that I know is "to appeal a ruling/decision", which means to appeal *against* the ruling or decision.

Here the relevant verb is *appeal to* something, mean to reference the thing, or to look to it for assistance.

Comment: There is also the archaic sense of _call to answer_ (as for a crime) which takes the preposition _of_, but that is a poor fit here.